# Strange placement of 'has' with commas around!

Tags: punctuation

Straight from the Cambridge IELTS test:

> Alan Macfarlane, professor of anthropological science at King's College, ***Cambridge, has,*** like other historians, spent decades wrestling with the enigma of the Industrial Revolution.

A simple question - I haven't observed such a strange use of punctuation marks. It's before and after *'has?*' How? Which rule? Why?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not 'has' - it's everything else in the sentence.

The basic sentence is 'Alan Macfarlane has spent decades wrestling with the enigma of the Industrial Revolution'. No comma needed. 'professor of anthropological science at King's College, Cambridge' is extra information about 'Alan Macfarlane', and needs commas around it. 'like other historians' is extra information about how he has done something, and also needs commas around it. This has the effect of placing one comma before 'has' and another one after it, but neither is related to 'has' itself.